# Can I share requests limit between two Facebook apps?

Tags: api, facebook, graph, instagram

I have two facebook apps. One is using Instagram basic display, and the other is using Instagram graph api. Users are authorized by basic display, so requests limit is extending on the first app. I use graph api to fetch users basic statistics with business discovery, but I have only 200 requests per hour since users are on the other app. Can I somehow share limit between two apps, or can I have both basic display and graph api on one app?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is that you'd need to have them authenticate on both apps so you'd have two different access tokens.